# Redirect from non-www to www. site slowing down page load time

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, pagespeed

The redirect from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` is slowing down the load time of my site, and even Google PageSpeed complains about the redirect. I am not entirely sure why this redirect happens, but from searching this site, I understand it has something to do with the `.htaccess` file. What should I do to increase speed? Remove the redirect? Change the code?

Comment: Because a redirect via the .htaccess file is a *header redirect*, which requires very little data to be sent to the client, it should be extremely fast. Could anything alse be the culprit?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, however the PageSpeed Insight says to remove that redirect and I even tested it in my browser. When I loaded each, the www. one was noticeably faster. I am running caching plugins, minifying plugins and I did optimize all the images. EDIT: It also says to improve server response times.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redirect in .htaccess; you don't need it to force www in the URL. To do that, add www to both URLs in Dashboard>>Settings>>General and remove any redirects you added in Bluehost's Cpanel.

See http://gtmetrix.com/reports/techneversleeps.com/8w6iAVLS Your site speed is not bad; if it greaty varies, talk to Bluehost; they could have an overloaded server.